# Angular 2 RouterLink for Select

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I would like to create navigation using a select element on my page. Using the RouterLink directive on an anchor tag is simple, but is there an equivalent for a select dropdown? Or am I required to create my own navigation method on my component to be called when there is a change on my select?

```html
<a [routerLink]="[location]">Location</a>

<select (change)="navigate($event.target.value)">
    <option>--Select Option--</option>
    <option [value]="[location]">Location</option>
</select>
```

I am looking for something like this:

```html
<select>
    <option>--Select Option--</option>
    <option [routerLink]="[location]">Location</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to create a navigation method inside your component and bind it to the `(change)` event of the select control and then do the navigation inside that method using an injected `Router`.

If you look into the Angular 2 Router [**source code**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts) for `RouterLink` directive, you'll see that it is also using `router.navigate` behind the scene to navigate to the target route. It won't work for your `select` control since select does not have a `click` event which is captured by the RouterLink directive as you can see below:

```
// ** Code below is copied from Angular source code on GitHub. **
@HostListener("click")
  onClick(): boolean {
    // If no target, or if target is _self, prevent default browser behavior
    if (!isString(this.target) || this.target == '_self') {
      this._router.navigate(this._commands, this._routeSegment);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Html template:

```
<select (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)">
    <option>--Select Option--</option>
    <option value="location">Location</option>
</select>
```

Component:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated'; //or updated version

constructor(private router: Router){}

navigateTo(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.router.navigate([value]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Really grateful, simple and it works, dont know about the good practices, but I didn't do angular and dont know anything about that but it works at once

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71779512/3044126